# Share CMake build folder between jobs in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, cmake

I'm building a pipeline in Azure DevOps that first builds a project using CMake and then, conditionally, creates an installer out of it. The creation of the installer is also done using CMake (and CPack). Since the installer is only supposed to be created and published under certain conditions (a tag is created), I'd like to share the `build` folder from the first job and reuse it in the second job. I do so by uploading the artifacts as the last step from the first job

```
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        pathToPublish: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build
        artifactName: build_release
```

(pipeline artifacts are currently not supported by our environment)

and downloading and moving it in the second step

```
    - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
      inputs:
        downloadType: 'single'
        artifactName: build_release
        downloadPath: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/tmp
    - task: CopyFiles@2
      displayName: Copy Artifacts into Build Directory
      inputs:
        SourceFolder: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/tmp/build_release
        TargetFolder: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build
```

Unfortunately, I'm running into an issue with cached absolute paths now:

```
CMake is re-running because D:/.../_work/171/s/build/vs-project/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp dependency file is missing.
CMake Error: The current CMakeCache.txt directory D:/.../_work/212/s/build/vs-project/CMakeCache.txt is different than the directory d:/.../_work/171/s/build/vs-project where CMakeCache.txt was created. This may result in binaries being created in the wrong place. If you are not sure, reedit the CMakeCache.txt
CMake Error: The source directory "D:/.../_work/171/s/build" does not exist.
```

I understand that several paths are cached in `CMakeCache.txt` and do not match since the build is taking place in a separate folder. Is there an elegant way to have ADO rewrite the paths in `CMakeCache.txt` automatically? Or to make sure the folder names stay constant for the two jobs?

Any help appreciated here!